# How can i search for text in a UITextView and delete the selected text from the view

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

New to Objective c so example would be appreciated.
What I'm trying to do is input text into a UITextfield and remove the occurrence of the text in a UITextView on IBAction.

All knowing in html,javascript and css.Hard to teach a old dog new tricks,but working on it.
Thanks in advance to all that reply.

```
-(IBAction)tel2{


[UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:tel2 cache:YES];
[UIButton setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIButton setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(test)];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:.5];

if(tails2.tag==11){
    [tel2 addSubview:tails2];
    tails2.tag=22;



    textField.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" %@", textField2.text];
}
else{
    [tel2 addSubview:heads2];
    tails2.tag=11;


    textField.text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", textField.text, textField2.text];

    }

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing much of what you are trying to do I think you could just use the replaceOccuranceOfString method with NSStriing (you can look it up but it's something like `NSString *newString = [oldString replaceOccuranceOfString:"what you want to replace" withString""];`.  But again it depends on what you are trying to accomplish in that IBAction, such as do you have a specific word that you want to remove or a list of words.

Comment: I input the word in the UITextfield,tap button and it deletes all occurrences of the word from the UITextView

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can do it

```
NSString* searchWord = @"word";

NSString* editedText = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:searchWord withString:@""];

textView.text = editedText;
```

Comment: Have added code snipet so you can have better idea of what I'm trying to acomplish

Answer (score 0):

0) in your view controller:

```
UITextField *fooTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, textFieldWidth, textFieldHeight)];
[self.view addSubview:fooTextField];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:fooTextField];
fooTextField.delegate = self; //you need to add a couple of delegate methods here also
```

1) then add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:fooTextField];
```

to your view controller's `viewDidLoad;` method

2) add the following method to your view controller class

```
   - (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
        NSString *currentTextInTextField = [NSString stringWithString:[(UITextField*)notification.object text]];
        if ([currentTextInTextField isEqualToString:@"thisIsTheStringYouAreLookingFor"]) {
            [(UITextField*)notification.object setText:@"whateverYouWantToReplaceItWith"];
        }
    }
```

3) You may wish to do some funky regex work on the match for `currentTextInField isEqualToString:` though that is a separate question

Comment: Have added code snipet so you can have better idea of what I'm trying to acomplish